# Is the verb form correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, british-english, language-formation

- "I will commit myself to acquiring a new skill."

I saw a sentence like this one (same structure, same verb form) on Cambridge Dictionary's website. But I checked it on Grammarly, and *it* said that the verb form is wrong. I don't understand why.

Comment: Checking for example sentences in other dictionaries is a good way to check. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commit), for instance, seems happy with << 'Our Office is committed, along with our law enforcement partners, to holding accountable those individuals who distribute fentanyl ...'
— Madeline Mitchell, Cincinnati.com,...14 Mar. 2020 >>
 and << 'All of us at Holland America Line are fully committed to supporting all our guests through this change.' 
— Los Angeles Times, "Cruise lines suspending ..." 13 Mar. 2020 >>. Grammarly seems in a minority here. I'm glad to say.

Comment: That said, the sentence sounds awkward, gawky even, not something I'd be comfortable with in conversation.

Comment: Will not rely on Grammarly next time

Comment: It's pretty good on occasion.